# Query only work items that are assigned to me in Team foundation server

Tags: tfs, workitem

We have projects in 3 Project Collections in TFS 2010.

Currently, when a user runs a work item query, that user can see all work items in the projects that they have access to.  How can I restrict this so that users can only view the work items where the `[Assigned To]` field is set to them?

Comment: Why is this off-topic?  This is a question about a bug tracking tool, thus "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: Thanks for your comment Edward! I think others didn't understand my seen! Note to **restrict**

Answer (score 3):

You can create new queries by right-clicking in Team Explorer. "My Work Items" is a popular query and may already have been created for you. Try editing a few existing queries to see how to structure them. Here's how mine looks in VS 2012 - if you're using 2010 the UI will be different, but not the syntax:

[image]

Comment: Oops! Yes I know how to use query editor and set various parameters and run them.But I want to a user can't access to other users work items.In the other hand, I want to manage user security permissions to view and edit only themselves work items[work items that assigned to them]. Thanks